# The subnet ID '10.0.4.0/24' is malformed (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, subnet, malformed

I've a error when I launch my stack on AWS and receive the error:

> The subnet ID '10.0.4.0/24' is malformed (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400)

[image: CloudFormation Error]

This is my stack:

```
    Parameters:
      KeyName:
        Description: Nom de la paire de cle pour l'acces aux instances EC2 via SSH 
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
        Default: 'CLEAWS'
      LanIPPub:
        Description: Adresse IP publique de l'entreprise
        Type: String
        Default: '82.64.110.122'
      LanNetwork:
        Description: Adresse du reseau local de l'entreprise a joindre via le VPN (CIDR Block)
        Type: String
        Default: '192.168.0.0/24'
      VPCAddress:
        Description: Adresse du VPC a creer (CIDR Block)
        Type: String
        Default: '10.0.0.0/16'
      PrivateNetwork:
        Description: Adresse du sous-reseau prive a creer (CIDR Block)
        Type: String
        Default: '10.0.1.0/24'
      PublicNetwork:
        Description: Adresse du sous-reseau public a creer (CIDR Block)
        Type: String
        Default: '10.0.4.0/24'

      AMIID:
        Description: ID de l'instance EC2 (AMI) a creer pour l'intranet
        Type: String
        Default: 'ami-0c6ebbd55ab05f070'
      IPIntranet:
        Description: IP a definir pour l'instance intranet situee dans le subnet prive
        Type: String
        Default: '172.32.1.80'
      
    Resources:
      VPC:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
        Properties:
          CidrBlock: !Ref VPCAddress
          EnableDnsHostnames: true
          EnableDnsSupport: true
          Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: 'vpc-infra'
      PrivateSubnet:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
        Properties:
          VpcId:
            Ref: VPC
          AvailabilityZone: eu-west-3c
          CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateNetwork
          Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: 'sub-priv-infra'
      InternetGateway:
        Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
        Properties:
          Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: 'infra-igw'
      AttachInternetGateway:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
        Properties:
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      NatEip:
        Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
        Properties:
          Domain: vpc
      NatGateway:
        DependsOn: AttachInternetGateway
        Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
        Properties:
          AllocationId: !GetAtt NatEip.AllocationId
          SubnetId: !Ref PublicNetwork
          Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: 'infra-gwnat'
      RouteTablePrivateSubnet:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
        Properties:
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: 'infra-route-pv-sub'
      RoutePrivateSubnetVPNAccess:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Route
        Properties:
          RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivateSubnet
          DestinationCidrBlock: !Ref LanNetwork
          GatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway 
        DependsOn: AttachVpnGateway  
      RoutePrivateSubnetWanAccess:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Route
        Properties:
          RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivateSubnet
          DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
          NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway
        DependsOn: NatEip 
      PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
        Properties:
          SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
          RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivateSubnet
        DependsOn:
          - PrivateSubnet
          - RouteTablePrivateSubnet
      SecGrpPriv:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
          GroupDescription: HTTP and SSH
          SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: icmp
              FromPort: -1
              ToPort: -1
              CidrIp: !Ref LanNetwork
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: 22
              ToPort: 22
              CidrIp: !Ref LanNetwork
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: 80
              ToPort: 80
              CidrIp: !Ref LanNetwork     
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          Tags:
           - Key: Name
             Value: infra-grp-sec-priv
      CustomerGateway: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway
        Properties: 
          Type: ipsec.1
          BgpAsn: 65000
          IpAddress: !Ref LanIPPub
          Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: lan-gw
      VPNGateway: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::VPNGateway
        Properties: 
          Type: ipsec.1
          Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: vpn-gw
      AttachVpnGateway:
        Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
        Properties:
          VpcId: !Ref VPC
          VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
      VPNConnection: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::VPNConnection
        Properties: 
          Type: ipsec.1
          StaticRoutesOnly: true
          CustomerGatewayId: !Ref CustomerGateway
          VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
          Tags:
           - Key: Name
             Value: vpn-aws-to-lan        
      ConnectionRoute: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::VPNConnectionRoute
        Properties: 
          DestinationCidrBlock: !Ref LanNetwork
          VpnConnectionId: !Ref VPNConnection
      IntranetEC2: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        DependsOn: ConnectionRoute
        Properties:
          ImageId: !Ref AMIID
          InstanceType: t2.micro
          PrivateIpAddress: !Ref IPIntranet
          KeyName: !Ref KeyName 
          SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
          SecurityGroupIds:
            - !Ref SecGrpPriv
          UserData:
            Fn::Base64:
              !Sub |
               #!/bin/bash
                sudo su apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

<!-- end snippet -->

  AMIID:
    Description: ID de l'instance EC2 (AMI) a creer pour l'intranet
    Type: String
    Default: 'ami-0c6ebbd55ab05f070'
  IPIntranet:
    Description: IP a definir pour l'instance intranet situee dans le subnet prive
    Type: String
    Default: '172.32.1.80'
  
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VPCAddress
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: 'vpc-infra'
  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-3c
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateNetwork
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: 'sub-priv-infra'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'infra-igw'
  AttachInternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  NatEip:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  NatGateway:
    DependsOn: AttachInternetGateway
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatEip.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicNetwork
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'infra-gwnat'
  RouteTablePrivateSubnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: 'infra-route-pv-sub'
  RoutePrivateSubnetVPNAccess:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivateSubnet
      DestinationCidrBlock: !Ref LanNetwork
      GatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway 
    DependsOn: AttachVpnGateway  
  RoutePrivateSubnetWanAccess:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivateSubnet
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway
    DependsOn: NatEip 
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivateSubnet
    DependsOn:
      - PrivateSubnet
      - RouteTablePrivateSubnet
  SecGrpPriv:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: HTTP and SSH
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: icmp
          FromPort: -1
          ToPort: -1
          CidrIp: !Ref LanNetwork
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: !Ref LanNetwork
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: !Ref LanNetwork     
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: infra-grp-sec-priv
  CustomerGateway: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway
    Properties: 
      Type: ipsec.1
      BgpAsn: 65000
      IpAddress: !Ref LanIPPub
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: lan-gw
  VPNGateway: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPNGateway
    Properties: 
      Type: ipsec.1
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: vpn-gw
  AttachVpnGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
  VPNConnection: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPNConnection
    Properties: 
      Type: ipsec.1
      StaticRoutesOnly: true
      CustomerGatewayId: !Ref CustomerGateway
      VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
      Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: vpn-aws-to-lan        
  ConnectionRoute: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPNConnectionRoute
    Properties: 
      DestinationCidrBlock: !Ref LanNetwork
      VpnConnectionId: !Ref VPNConnection
  IntranetEC2: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: ConnectionRoute
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref AMIID
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      PrivateIpAddress: !Ref IPIntranet
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName 
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecGrpPriv
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
           #!/bin/bash
            sudo su apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Can you help me please? thank

Comment: Just checking -- there seems to be lines that are duplicated in the above template -- could you please check? For example, there are two `Resources` sections. Can you update with the complete template so that we can try it ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a subnet ID, that's the CIDR block of a subnet. You should be using a reference to `PublicSubnet` not `PublicNetwork`.

Comment: Oh thank ! 

I fixed the error by replacing "PublicNetwork" with "PublicSubnet"

But I still get the above error